# How to find the minimum number of coins needed for a given target amount(different from existing ones)

Tags: c, dynamic-programming

This is a classic question, where a list of coin amounts are given in `coins[]`, `len` = length of `coins[]` array, and we try to find minimum amount of coins needed to get the `target`.

The coins array is sorted in ascending order

NOTE: I am trying to optimize the efficiency. Obviously I can run a for loop through the coins array and add the `target%coins[i]` together, but this will be erroneous when I have for example `coins[] = {1,3,4}` and `target = 6`, the for loop method would give 3, which is 1,1,4, but the optimal solution is 2, which is 3,3.

I haven't learned matrices and multi-dimensional array yet, are there ways to do this problem without them? I wrote a function, but it seems to be running in an infinity loop.

```
int find_min(const int coins[], int len, int target) {
    int i;
    int min = target;
    int curr;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (target == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (coins[i] <= target) {
            curr = 1 + find_min(coins, len, target - coins[i]);
            if (curr < min) {
                min = curr;
            }
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: You should show the function header. -- The infinite loop is probably due to the fact that you don't handle the situation where the sum goes over the target (`target - coins[i]` becomes negative).

Comment: Function header added, I also added if condition to make sure `target>=coins[i]`, unfortunately, problem not resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one gives a good answer, and that I figured it out myself. I might as well post an answer.

I add an array called lp, which is initialized in main,

```
int lp[4096];
int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= COINS_MAX_TARGET; i++) {
        lp[i] = -1;
    }
```

every index of lp is equal to -1.

```
int find_min(int tar, const int coins[], int len, int lp[])
{
    // Base case
    if (tar == 0) {
        lp[0] = 0;
        return 0;
    }

    if (lp[tar] != -1) {
        return lp[tar];
    }

    // Initialize result
    int result = COINS_MAX_TARGET;

    // Try every coin that is smaller than tar
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        if (coins[i] <= tar) {

            int x  = find_min(tar - coins[i], coins, len, lp);

            if (x != COINS_MAX_TARGET)
                result = ((result > (1 + x)) ? (1+x) : result);
        }
    }

    lp[tar] = result;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you this reading,

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-a-combination-of-minimum-coins-that-results-to-a-given-value/

the only thing is that there is no C version of the code, but if really need it you can do the porting by yourself.